# cmake：Could NOT find NUMA (missing: NUMA_LIBRARIES)

Tags: cmake

I use cmake to compile a project.
But I get

```
-- Could NOT find NUMA (missing: NUMA_LIBRARIES) 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
NUMA_LIBRARIES (ADVANCED)
```

I've had numactl numactl-devel installed.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

This is actually a problem with the lack of Open MPI, not NUMA. What you need to do is installing the OPEN MPI binary either from source ([https://webpages.charlotte.edu/~abw/coit-grid01.uncc.edu/ParallelProgSoftware/Software/OpenMPIInstall.pdf](https://webpages.charlotte.edu/%7Eabw/coit-grid01.uncc.edu/ParallelProgSoftware/Software/OpenMPIInstall.pdf)) or from the APT repo:

```
sudo apt install openmpi-bin
```

Comment: For me I had to install libnuma-dev via '''sudo apt install libnuma-dev'''